# Why thread dump core if i don't join main thread

Tags: multithreading

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    thread t1([]{
        cout<<"Hi";
        });
    //t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

if i will comment t1.join() it generate dump.

Comment: When `main` ends, thread destructor is called. If thread is in joinable state, then `terminate` is called, which calls `abort`. Before thread destructor is called, thread must be detached or joined. See [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Comment: It's meant to help you by making it harder to write a program that can leave dangling threads.  The std::thread() destructor will throw an error if you don't either (a) join the thread (i.e., ensure that the thread has finished its work) before the destructor is called or (b), `detach` the thread, which basically is you saying, "trust me! I know what I'm doing."

Comment: @SolomonSlow it's really helpful.thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

The true-but-uninteresting answer is because that is what the implementers of the threading library programmed it to do.

The more interesting answer is *why* they programmed it to behave that way.  The reason they have the thread panic in this situation is to make an obscure problem more obvious (and thus easier to detect and fix sooner rather than later).

The obscure problem is a race condition:  A process's C or C++ runtime sets up some process-wide shared-resources (e.g. tables of environment-variable names, stdio buffers, etc) before main() is called, and then tears them down again after main() returns (but before the process is destroyed).  In a single-threaded program, that's no problem, because your single-threaded code never executes before or after main(), so your code never has to worry about trying to use these data structures while they are in a not-fully-formed state.

However, if you start a second thread running, and that thread is still running after main() returns, that means your thread has a small (but non-zero) chance of trying to access one of those process-wide data structures at the exact moment that the runtime is busy cleaning it up and removing it -- and thus "seeing" it in some undefined/half-destroyed state that is not safe to use.  The symptom of this would be that very occasionally (e.g. once in a hundred runs, or even less) your program would mysteriously crash (or otherwise misbehave) while exiting, and it could be very difficult for you to figure out why that was happening and fix it.

The fix to that problem is to make sure that main() calls `join()` on the thread before exiting, so that you can guarantee that your thread is no longer running when the data-structures start being cleaned up.  And the deliberate-panic-trap is there to make sure you realize right away that you need to do that (or alternatively call `detach()` to indicate that you are aware of the problem and don't care -- but if so, you'd better know what you are doing, or you're back to square one)